# Publish in ArXiv/Munich Personal RePEc Archive/SSRN

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate, arxiv, online-publication

I have just finished my paper on case study in quantitative finance, and thinking of publishing my work. Although, I am an undergraduate student and getting published in a decent academic journal requires both funds and many months until the final decision after a potential acceptance. My thought was to share my work in a repository such as ArXiv, Munich Personal RePEc or SSRN Electronic Journal to share the results.

My questions are:

1) whether I am eligible sharing in the aforementioned, since the paper is not a working paper and I am not willing to get into the publishing process.

2) Is my work safe and equivalent in terms of copyrights as a published paper in a peer-review journal?

Comment: Why do you think "getting published in a decent academic journal requires...funds"? Also, did you do the case study under the supervision of an academic?

Answer (score 1):

In the cae of ArXiv:

1) Yes. However, your paper needs to be endorsed by an established academic. See ArXiv's help on the endorsement system: https://arxiv.org/help/endorsement

2) You need to give ArXiv a perpetual license to distribute your work. But otherwise you retain the copyright. With a traditional subscription-based journal, you would typically have to give your copyright to the journal.